# How can I compare two name strings that are formatted differently in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

What would be the best approach for comparing the following set of strings in SQL Server?

Purpose: The main purpose of this Stored Procedure is to compare a set of input Names of Customers to names that Exist in the Customer database for a specific accounts. If there is a difference between the input name and the name in the Database this should trigger the updating of the Customer Database with the new name information.

### Conditions:

Format of Input: `FirstName [MiddleName] LastName`

Format of Value in Database: `LastName, FirstName MiddleName`

The complication arises when names like this are presented,

### Example:

Input: `Dr. John A. Mc Donald`

Database: `Mc Donald, Dr. John A.`

For last names that consist of 2 or more parts what logic would have to be put into place
to ensure that the lastname in the input is being compared to the lastname in the database and likewise for the first name and middle name.

I've thought about breaking the database values up into a temp HASH table since I know that everything before the ',' in the database is the last name. I could then check to see if the input contains the lastname and split out the `FirstName [MiddleName]` from it to perform another comparison to the database for the values that come after the ','.

There is a second part to this however. In the event that the input name has a completely New last name (i.e. if the name in the database is Mary Smith but the updated input name is now Mary Mc Donald). In this case comparing the database value of the last name before the ',' to the input name will result in no match which is correct, but at this point how does the code know where the last name even begins in the input value? How does it know that her Middle name isn't MC and her last name Donald?

Has anyone had to deal with a similar problem like this before? What solutions did you end up going with?

I greatly appreciate your input and ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like something that should be handled in your application, not in your database logic.

Comment: The input records will be in the thousands. This is why there is a preference to a Database-centric solution.

Comment: T-SQL is not very powerful in terms of string manipulation - any chance you could create a .NET assembly in C# or VB.NET and deploy it into your SQL Server?? That would open doors to regular expresions and much more!

Comment: Heck, even in something like PowerShell which is .NET based.

Comment: @user509693, can we assume that the Customer's ID will be stored on both the input and existing database tables? Will FirstName include the customer's title (eg. Dr.) always/sometimes/never? Also, does the `[]` indicate that middle names are optional in the input, so that eg. input 'John Mc Donald' should be regarded as the same as 'Mc Donald, John Arthur'?

Comment: That's correct. the new input data and the existing customer data are linked by a common CustomerID. In the event that they are legitimately different, the code is then charged with Updating the Customer Database with the new Values in its format of 'LastName, Firstname MiddleName'. the FirstName will only sometimes include the title as well as MiddleName. The final example you listed should come back as a difference and in turn trigger the updating of the Customer Database.

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, it's extremely computationally difficult (if not impossible) to know if a name like "Mary Jane Evelyn Scott" is first-middle-last1-last2, first1-first2-middle-last, first1-first2-last1-last2, or some other combination... and that's not even getting into cultural considerations...

So personally, I would suggest a change in the data structure (and, correspondingly, the application's input fields).  Instead of a single string for name, break it into several fields, e.g.:

```
FullName{
  title,      //i.e. Dr., Professor, etc.
  firstName,  //or given name
  middleName, //doesn't exist in all countries!
  lastName,   //or surname
  qualifiers  //i.e. Sr., Jr., fils, D.D.S., PE, Ph.D., etc.
}
```

Then the user could choose that their first name is "Mary", their middle name is "Jane Evelyn", and their last name is "Scott".

**UPDATE**
Based on your comments, if you must do this entirely in SQL, I'd do something like the following:

1. Build a table for all possible combinations of "lastname, firstname [middlename]" given an input string "firstname [middlename] lastname"
2. Run a query based on the join of your original data and all possible orderings.

So, step 1. would take the string "Dr. John A. Mc Donald" and create the table of values:

```
'Donald, Dr. John A. Mc'
'Mc Donald, Dr. John A.'
'A. Mc Donald, Dr. John'
'John A. Mc Donald, Dr.'
```

Then step 2. would search for all occurrences of any of those strings in the database.

Assuming MSSQL 2005 or later, step 1. can be achieved using some recursive CTE, and a modification of a method I've used to split CSV strings (found [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3634381/Dealing-with-Comma-Delimited-Strings.htm)) (SQL isn't the ideal language for this form of string manipulation...):

```
declare @str varchar(200)
set @str = 'Dr. John A. Mc Donald'

--Create a numbers table
select [Number] = identity(int)
into #Numbers
from sysobjects s1
    cross join sysobjects s2

create unique clustered index Number_ind on #Numbers(Number) with IGNORE_DUP_KEY

;with nameParts as (
    --Split the name string at the spaces.
    select [ord] = row_number() over(order by Number),
        [part] = substring(fn1, Number, charindex(' ', fn1+' ', Number) - Number)
    from (select @str fn1) s
        join #Numbers n on substring(' '+fn1, Number, 1) = ' '
    where Number<=Len(fn1)+1

),
lastNames as (
    --Build all possible lastName strings.
    select [firstOrd]=ord, [lastOrd]=ord, [lastName]=cast(part as varchar(max))
    from nameParts
    where ord!=1 --remove the case where the whole string is the last name
    UNION ALL
    select firstOrd, p.ord, l.lastName+' '+p.part
    from lastNames l
        join nameParts p on l.lastOrd+1=p.ord
),
firstNames as (
    --Build all possible firstName strings.
    select [firstOrd]=ord, [lastOrd]=ord, [firstName]=cast(part as varchar(max))
    from nameParts
    where ord!=(select max(ord) from nameParts) --remove the case where the whole string is the first name
    UNION ALL
    select p.ord, f.lastOrd, p.part+' '+f.firstName
    from firstNames f
        join nameParts p on f.firstOrd-1 = p.ord
)
--Combine for all possible name strings.
select ln.lastName+', '+fn.firstName
from firstNames fn
    join lastNames ln on fn.lastOrd+1=ln.firstOrd
where fn.firstOrd=1
    and ln.lastOrd = (select max(ord) from nameParts)

drop table #Numbers
```

Comment: In our case we receive this data from a third party that is not able to change the format. So the initial issue of deciphering which portions of the string go to where after being split on ' ' remains.

Comment: That's unfortunate... is there a reason you're storing the name in the format "lastname, firstname [middlename]", instead of the format you're receiving it in (i.e. "firstname [middlename] lastname"?

Comment: That is something that could be changed in the future on our end but there are currently many dependent processes that expect the data to be in that format on our side. The main issue remains, which is how to split a string consisting of 'FirstName [MiddleName] LastName' into a format that can be compared to a string consisting of 'LastName, FirstName [MiddleName]'

Answer (score 1):

Since I had my share of terrible experience with data from third parties, it is almost guaranteed that the input data will contain lots of garbage not following the specified format.
When trying to match data multipart string data like in your case, I preprocessed both input and our data into something I called "normalized string" using the following method.

1. strip all non-ascii chars (leaving language-specific chars like "č" intact)
2. compact spaces (replace multiple spaces with single one)
3. lower case
4. split into words
5. remove duplicates
6. sort alphabetically
7. join back to string separated by dashes

Using you sample data, this function would produce:

> Dr. John A. Mc Donald ->
>   a-donald-dr-john-mc
>  Mc Donald, Dr.
>   John A.-> a-donald-dr-john-mc

Unfortunaly it's not 100% bulletproof, there are cases where degenerated inputs produce invalid matches.

Answer (score 0):

Your name field is bad in the database. Redesign and get rid of it. If you havea a first name, middlename, lastname, prefix and suffix sttructure, you can hava computed filed that has the structure you are using.  But it is a very poor way to store data and your first priority should be to stop using it.

Since you have a common customer Id why aren't you matching on that instead of name?

Comment: In our case we receive this data from a third party that is not able to change the format. So the initial issue of deciphering which portions of the string go to where after being split on ' ' remains. The CustomerID is only used to match the record in the DB with the one coming in from the 3rd party. We still need to compare the Name fields stored in each in order to determine if the Customer Database name associated with that given account needs to be updated.